# How to add a public key into system keyring for kernel without recompile?

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-modules, key-authentication

I want to add a public key from the keypair that I used to sign my kernel module, into system_keyring. However, there's a problem:

With the command of `cat /proc/keys | grep system_keyring`, I've got the entry (ID) of system_keyring. However, when trying to add my public key with this command: `keyctl padd asymmetric "" 0xXXXXXXXX</test/signing_key.x509`, I've got `Permission denied" error.

I think it is due to the restriction described in the "module_signing.txt" https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/admin-guide/module-signing.html :

> Note, however, that the kernel will only permit keys to be added to
>   .system_keyring *if* the new key's X.509 wrapper is validly signed by a key
>   that is already resident in the .system_keyring at the time the key was added.

However, I cannot find any document to describe how to sign the "X.509 wrapper" with the key already resident in the .system_keyring.

Also, I think the keys in that keyring is only public key. So, I don't even think it will work, even if I can extract the public key out of the keyring and sign the "X.509 wrapper" with that public key.

Anyway, need some help here. Or, even if something can give me a hint of how to submit my kernel module to RedHat so that it can be signed by RedHat and installed on user's installation without rebuild the kernel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system keyring gets its contents from five sources:

- keys embedded in kernel at compile time (obviously not changeable without recompiling)
- UEFI Secure Boot variable `db` - depending on your firmware, you might or might not be able to change this
- UEFI Secure Boot variable `dbx`- as the previous one, but this is a blacklist so you would not want to add your key here anyway
- keys embedded in `shim.efi` - not changeable without recompiling, and you would probably have to get the shim re-signed afterwards unless you have taken control of your secure boot `PK` = too much of a hassle
- UEFI variable `MOK` (used by `shim.efi`) - this might be your best hope.

To import your key into MOK, you should first ensure that `shim.efi` is involved in your boot process (see `efibootmgr -v`).

Then have the key/certificate that your module is signed with in DER format, and start the import process using the `mokutil` command:

```
mokutil --import your_signing_key.pub.der
```

The command will require you to set a new import password: this password will be used in the next step, and is not any password that exists before. As usual when setting a new password, `mokutil` will require you to type this password twice.

Then, next time you reboot the system, `shim.efi` will see that a new MOK key is ready for importation, and *it will require you to type the import password* you set in the previous step. After you've done this once, the new key will be stored in the UEFI MOK variable persistently, and the kernel will automatically include it in the system keyring.

If you are not using UEFI, you cannot add new keys to the system keyring without recompiling the kernel. But on the other hand, if Secure Boot is not enabled, the kernel will allow loading of kernel modules with no signature or with an unverifiable signature - it just sets one of the kernel's taint flags to mark that a non-distribution kernel module has been loaded.

Source: [RHEL 7 Kernel Administration Guide, Chapter 2.8 "Signing Kernel Modules for Secure Boot"](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Kernel_Administration_Guide/sect-signing-kernel-modules-for-secure-boot.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. However, mokutil doesn't works for me:( I've got the error message like this:
`EFI variables are not supported on this system` 
Since this is a VM not configured with EFI enabled.

Comment: And indeed, the kernel module does load properly. However, the dmesg warning message is annoying...but seems like I'll need to learn to live with it then.

Comment: Many thanks to "telcoM's" answer to my question. It provide important information, guidance as well as confidence for me to systematically understand the issue, and get to solution as well as verified the solution. So, basically: 
  1. I'm using VMWare workstation to do the testing. I've enabled the secure boot, and validate the mokutil + enroll the key into EFI works. 
  2. Noticed that for CentOS/RHEL7.5, this doesn't work well. I found this: https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=13420 which seems to be a know issue (still not been fixed?!).

Comment: I'm lacking knowledge about this facility. sorry if i'm wrong. kernel 5.17 don't read keys from MOK if secureboot disabled( `the MOK/MOKx can not be trusted when secure boot is disabled` [commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/security/integrity/platform_certs/load_uefi.c#L215) ). but i still can enforce module signature check via bootarg `module.sig_enforce` . MOK way seems useless after kernel 5.17

Comment: @KevinChan If you don't use Secure Boot, a malicious bootloader could modify your kernel code to make the module signature check always be accepted. If you build your own kernels, the kernel build process will create its own temporary signing key **if you don't provide one**, and will sign the modules built from the kernel source package with it. So you could provide your own signing key and use it to sign any third-party modules too. The kernel option is CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY, it can point to a file that contains both the private & public key in PEM format.

Comment: @telcoM Thanks for further explanation. i know details you mentions.  Without Secure Boot, MOK is unreliable and there's no way to enroll keys to kernel without recompiling
 it( because system_keyring unknown ). Is this correct?

Comment: The kernel might allow enrolling keys *that are signed with a key that is already trusted by the kernel*. But the only key the kernel initially trusts (without Secure Boot) is the key the kernel was built with, and if it was autogenerated by the build process, the private key is probably wiped once the signing is done. If you supplied the initial key & certificate for the kernel build process, you could use that private key to sign other keys to make the kernel accept them, and/or to sign kernel modules built separately from the main kernel package. It's a "root-of-trust" issue.